# JSON data formetter in a particular way

Tags: javascript, json

I am using javascript.I have a json data set. I am trying to convert in a particular way. Can someone write the function so that I can convert it.

**Given Json data:**

```
{
   "members":[
      {
         "value":"view",
         "code":"reservations"
      },
      {
         "value":"view",
         "code":"dashboard"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Trying to convert in:**

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "view_reservation": true,
      "edit_reservation": true,
      "create_reservation": true,
      "delete_reservation": true
    },
    {
      "view_dashboard": true,
      "edit_dashboard": true,
      "create_dashboard": true,
      "delete_dashboard": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone write a function in javascript to convert it...

Comment: Given array doesn't match. Provide codes or minimal example. We can't pretend what you are trying to do

Comment: _"Can someone write the function so that I can convert it."_ - not really, we're here to help you write it, not write it for you. Please may you add a [mcve] of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
data.members = data.members.map(member => ({
  `${member.view}_${member.code}`: true,
  `edit_${member.code}`: true,
  `create_${member.code}`: true,
  `delete_${member.code}`: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you multiply output, we can just assume, that you always get 4 rows (CRUD-like)

Anyway, the approach of converting your object/array to the desired output can be done using something like this (where x is your current object):

```
var y = { "members": [] };
x.members.forEach(element => { y.members.push({ [element.code + '_' + element.value]: true}) } );
```

you can just edit the new object in the y.members.push to your desire